# hidden field not bind value details view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have one `DetailsView` named *DetailsView1*.In `InsertItemTemplate` i add one `HiddenField` named *MeasureProcessId*.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MeasureProcessId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("MeasureProcessId") %>'/>
```

In *page_load* method i add this:

```
 if (Request.QueryString["mid"] != null)
              {
                  string MeasureProcessId = Request.QueryString["mid"];
                  (DetailsView1.FindControl("MeasureProcessId") as HiddenField).Value = MeasureProcessId;
              }
```

but when i insert an entity i get error that value not bound.

Comment: Add details about error you are getting. And if possible share full code

Comment: chk value on debug mode

Comment: in debuge mode MeasureProcessId.value bound but in entity not bound

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`<asp:HiddenField ID="MeasureProcessId" runat="server" Value='<%# Request.QueryString["mid"] %>'/>`